# Logrotate doesn't work

Tags: linux, centos7, logrotate

Log rotate doesn't work very well.

So, when i execute command, I got a below error first time.

```
$ logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/systemname

error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status.tmp: Permission denied
```

then i changed `/var/lib/logrotate/` to 666

Error message change like below.

```
$ logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/systemname

error: error stat()ing state file /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status: Permission denied
```

Help me, how to solve this problem?

*thanks.*

Comment: `/etc` is the domain of the root user; execute `logrotate` with `root` permissions. Typically `logrotate` is not performed manually, but from `crontab`...

Comment: Thank you. It seems like, my misake. It may be no problem.       sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/systemname

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you tried to run logrotate as unprivileged user (`$` in the prompt), so you had no permissions for `/var/lib/logrotate/`.